# Only has class show, other divs hide via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<div>
  <h3>Past Events</h3>
  <section class="event past-event">
    . ..
  </section>

  <section class="event">
    ...
  </section>
</div>
```

I want only if has 'Past Events' title, show `past-event`, hide `event` div via jQuery. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Check the text of the `h3`

```
function showSections() {
    if ($("div h3").text() == "Past Events") {
        $(".event").hide();
        $(".past-event").show();
    } else {
        $(".event").hide();
        $(".event:not(.past-event)").show();
    }
}
```

A unique ID on the `h3` would probably help quite a bit, the function above is pretty generic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
$("h3:contains('Past Events')").siblings("section.event").hide();
$("h3:contains('Past Events')").siblings("section.past-event").show();
```

If you can be more specific what you are trying to do, that can help write the exact code.